# Trying to fix css and html to work together

Tags: html, css

im trying to make Grid system with HTML and CSS but when i add some images to the system some of them jump all around(i think that it's because of pixels mismatch) and when i resize the window(because it should also be responsive) they line up kinda of funny and i don't understand where is my problem. So i'm asking you for help. Here is JSFiddle from my work.

i think that i should modify this line to make it work but im not sure.

Comment: Unless you are setting all of the images to be responsive and you match the responsive percentage to the grid column percentages, you will have this issue. Images don't scale automatically. I'm also noticing that your column classes are not set up with the correct percentages. If 12 columns is 100%, then 6 should be 50%. Your column-6 is 49.2%.

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/nj9me653/ for a correctly implemented grid system. Just remember to keep your images responsive so that they have `max-width` set to no more than the size of the column they are in.

Comment: That's exactly *the* problem. If you allow an image to grow to its full native size - that size can wind up being bigger than the container of the image. The `max-width` should match the size of the container.

Comment: Responsive images should have their `width` property set to a relative unit (`%`, `em`, `vh`, `vw`, etc.). This way, when their parent element's width changes, they scale along with that parent (ensuring that they remain proportional to it). `min-width` and `max-width` just guard against whatever that relative size winds up being not being too big or too small (and so generally, we want those to be fixed values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is `margin` is in pixels and the `width` is in `%`. so 15% * 5 + 23*5 > 100% of the screen.

you need to shift the margin to % so that the sum is always 100.

```
15*5 = 75;  
remaining space for margins = 25% / 5 = 5 for each box
```

so
change your column styling to

```
.column{
  margin:23px 2.5%'
 }
```

**the  shifting problem**

have a look at the code:

every `p` has a background

```
 #farbig_logo_mercedes {
 background: url(http://www.seat-styler.de/wp-   content/uploads/2017/02/Mercedes_logo_ori.png) no-repeat center top;
```

}

means the image is of full size and is shifted only top 65 pixels is shown and is center aligned.

and the same `p` has a child `img` with the same `src`

```
<img class="logos_bild alignnone" src="http://www.seat-styler.pl/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2017/02/Mercedes_logo_edit.png" alt=" Mercedes Logo" width="65" height="65">
```

this has a specific height and width and the image adjusts into the 65x65 sqaure.

this is the image that is displayed. on hover, the opacity of img tag is set to 0 leaving the background image to show.

when there is difference in alignment of these two images, your icons dance on hover.

it is adviced NOT to use two images , one in bg and other as src especially ina responsive design like this.

if you want to use two images, use **both** as `background`

```
 p{
  background-image:url(1)
  }
p:hover{
   background-image:url(2)
  }
```

or you could use filters  on `img`

```
img {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
filter: sepia(100%);
opacity:0.5
 }
 img:hover{
filter:none;
opacity:1
}
```

**broken column #2**

this is because `.farbig_logo_ford` has a height greater than the others;
 add

```
 .column{ max-height:113px;}
```

also consider using `flex`

```
  .row{ display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;}
  .column{width:15%;}
```

remove float

https://jsfiddle.net/pmzg1nbu/3/

Comment: @JohnDoe where did you add the margin. add it to your `.column`

Comment: @JohnDoe  i have updated my answer with the working code. have a look.

Comment: they are not jumping. they shift a little because of the sprite positioning. it is not a prblem of responsive.

Comment: @JohnDoe your question wasn't clear. now i have updated my anwser. i hope this solves your problem

Comment: i know what you did and WHY you did it, i just pointed out that it causes problems in the responsive designs

Comment: it is because of different height.